# Fetching Data based date and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I am trying to find results from today onwards but also want to include the yesterdays plans if the time is between `12:00am-5:00am`

Right now i have the following

```
def self.current
    where(
      "plan_date >= :today",
      today: Date.current,
    )
end
```

Is there a way i can know the time of the day based on the users timezone which am setting as bellow in the app controller and make sure that if its before 6:am the next day i want to include the previous days results as well.

```
def set_time_zone(&block)
    if current_user
      Time.use_zone(current_user.time_zone_name, &block)
    else
      yield
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.current
    where(
      "plan_date >= :today",
      today: (Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(get_user_time_zone) - 6.hours).beginning_of_day,
    )
end
```

...where `get_user_time_zone` returns the time zone for the user (E.G.: `America/New_York`). I'm using `- 6.hours` because you wanted it to be "before 6am" local time.